# Question regarding generics and inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, inheritance

I have a class `Derived<T>` that is derived from `Base<T>`. Which of the following assertions are true or false?

```
typeof(Derived<SomeType>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base<SomeType>))
typeof(Derived<>)        .IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base<SomeType>))
typeof(Derived<SomeType>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base<>))
typeof(Derived<>)        .IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base<>))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like this should be tagged homework

Comment: @Chris: No. This isn't homework. I am not even a student. I miss the simplicity of C++, in which templates weren't anything but sophisticated (and somewhat convoluted) macros. (But, then, you couldn't test anything about templates, because they didn't exist at runtime.) :S

Comment: @Linkgoron: I am struggling with a lot of open projects, the last thing I want to do is open yet another slow instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: create a new console application inside one of your solutions. set it as the start-up project. no new instance of Visual Studio needed.

Comment: Or get TestDriven.net, write the method, and right-click to test.  Or .NET Pad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, the first one:

```
typeof(Derived<SomeType>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base<SomeType>))
```

The other's don't compile- you cannot refer to a generic without it's type argument, e.g.

```
Something<>
```

Comment: @Chris Slain: WRONG! `typeof(Derived<>)` is valid code. In fact, I am writing a **HUGE** metaprogramming framework that **RELIES** upon being able to refer to generics at runtime. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx

Comment: I stand corrected- you can compile that.  But the answer is still #1.

Comment: @Chris Shain: Sorry, I misstyped (actually, miss-saw) your name.

Comment: @Chris: Yes the answer was correct. Meh, cannot undo the downvote.

Comment: @Eduardo Leon: Undo the downvote by clicking it again(downvoting*2). I'm not kidding!!!

Comment: Its all good...  The reasoning, for whatever it is worth, is that the type argument actually becomes part of the type.  So Base<String> is actually a different type than Base<Int32>.  What is key to note here is that this is dependent upon the fact that the type variable flows from the definition of Derived to the definition of Base (e.g. Derived<*T*> : Base<*T*>), resulting in a different type of Base for each type of Derived. If Derived<T> : Base<String>, that would be a different situation.